# How to rename PDF form fields using PDF Sharp?

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp

I am using PDF Sharp and have one issue only. I cannot rename form **fields**. We have a field called 'x' and after an operation is applied to field 'x', it needs to be renamed to field 'y'.

I have seen tons of documentation on how to do this using **itextSharp**. Unfortunately my firm cannot use them and so I am looking for a solution using **PDF Sharp**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Field names are very well protected in PDF, and it is not thaat elementary to programmatically change them. A workaround would be (if PDF Sharp supports that) to read out all properties of the field, delete it, and recreate a new field with the new name and the properties of the original field. Note that this is the procedure using Acrobat JavaScript, and therefore works per se.

Comment: @MaxWyss: Yes, only iTextSharp offer a simple method to change the field names. I have come across many articles that match your opening statement. In the end we created a seperate template with the new field as a work-around.

Answer (score 2):

This can give you an idea on how to perform the field renaming

```
var uniqueIndex = Guid.NewGuid();
var fields = pdfDocument.AcroForm.Fields;
var fieldNames = fields.Names;

  for (int idx = 0; idx < fieldNames.Length; ++idx)
  {
      var fieldName = fieldNames[idx];
      var field = fields[fieldName];

      field.Elements.SetName($"/{fieldName}", $"{fieldName}_{uniqueIndex}");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to rename form field via PdfSharp as follow:

```
public void RenameAcroField(PdfAcroField field, string newFieldName)
{
    field.Elements.SetString("/T", newFieldName);
}
```

Little bit tricky but worked for my case. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET version for PDFsharp 1.50.5147

```
Dim i = 0
While i < pdfDoc.AcroForm.Fields.Count
  pdfDoc.AcroForm.Fields(i).Elements.SetString("/T", "formField" & i)
  i += 1
End While
```